# Cython, confusion regarding the vector (size) constructor

Tags: python, c++, cython

EDIT: FYI for anyone coming across this now just use pybind11 and don't waste your time on this (cython stuff)

It seems like the only way to do define a `vector` variable is

`cdef std::vector[int]* vec=new vector[int](<size>)`

Am I correct in thinking this? Here's sample code, if I compile and run this Python crashes at the end (VS2015, Python 3.5).

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
def test():
    cdef vector[int]* vec = new vector[int](5)
    cdef int i
    for i in range(5):
        print(vec[i])

    del vec
```

I want to have a 2 dimensional vector, with a certain size. How would I do this? Would it be:

`cdef std::vector[std::vector[int]]* vec=new vector[vector[int](<size1>)](<size2>)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although the official examples show how to create this stuff on the heap, for some reason, it's not really necessary. This code builds:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector                                                                                                                                                                          


ctypedef vector[int] int_vec                                                        
ctypedef vector[int_vec] int_vec_vec                                                


def test():                                                                         
    cdef int_vec v                                                                  
    v = int_vec(5)                                                                  

    cdef int_vec_ve vv                                                              
    vv = int_vec_vec(5, v)
```

It builds a 5X5 vector of int vectors.